Pourquoi "Devoirs Faits" est au passé ?
Au collège il y a des créneaux « Devoirs Faits ». Sur le site de l'éducation nationale on explique que ce dispositif est :

un temps d’étude accompagnée pour réaliser leurs devoirs.

Si c'est prévu que les devoirs sont à faire, pourquoi utiliser le passé ?

Où as-tu vu un passé ?

Si les devoirs restent "à faire" ou "en cours d'être faits", l'objectif n'est pas vraiment atteint !

Devoirs faits représente l'objectif de ce dispositif. Ici faits est un adjectif plus qu'un participe passé, mais ça ne change pas grand chose : devoir effectués, devoirs terminés.
Le programme vise simplement à lutter contre les devoirs non faits ou pas faits.
Comme le dit la page référencée dans la question:

L'objectif est de faire bénéficier les collégiens d'une aide appropriée au sein du collège afin de rentrer chez eux "Devoirs faits".


Les devoirs seront faits quand vos enfants quitteront le collège.

OK donc : Objectif《 Devoirs faits 》!

@DJDaveMark Oui comme pourrait être un programme nommé Mission accomplie anticipant la réussite de ladite mission.
